# Is a shared secret even necessary when using RSA256 (asymmetric) signed JWT?

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver3, openid-connect, identityserver4

One often reads that the ResourceOwnerCredentials Flow is bad because there can not be a secret key involved with an untrusted client (lika a Javascript or mobile Application).

Is this even valid if the tokens are signed asymmetrically and can be validated by the client using the public key JWK (Json Web Key) provided by the OAuth 2.0 server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misinterpreted the "Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant" ([link to spec.)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3).

What this flow does is, substitution resource owner's (if it's a person, it will be the end user) credentials with authorisation code. As the specification says it can be used to replace legacy systems which for example use basic authentication. And to this to be done, trust should be established between client and resource owner. Found a good article which you can read more on this [link](http://andyfiedler.com/2014/09/how-secure-is-the-oauth2-resource-owner-password-credential-flow-for-single-page-apps)

On the other hand, Client Credentials Grant is a grant which requires client to obtain and maintain ([link to spec.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4)). And this grant is only applicable to confidential clients

> The client credentials grant type MUST only be used by confidential
> clients.

I believe you have confused about two different grant types. As you have already seen, mobile applications and JavaScript applications are public client. So the client credential grant cannot be used for them.

Furthermore, once can indeed validate tokens using public key but to do that one should obtain tokens by completing a valid flow.

For a confidential client, shared secret can be used to encrypt the token. But this cannot be done for a public client as they cannot maintain a shared secret.

Anyway here are use cases for using client authentication (as described in specification : [Client authentication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.2.1))

> - Enforcing the binding of refresh tokens and authorization codes to
>   the client they were issued to.  Client authentication is critical
>   when an authorization code is transmitted to the redirection
>   endpoint over an insecure channel or when the redirection URI has
>   not been registered in full.
> - Recovering from a compromised client by disabling the client or
>   changing its credentials, thus preventing an attacker from abusing
>   stolen refresh tokens.  Changing a single set of client
>   credentials is significantly faster than revoking an entire set of
>   refresh tokens.
> - Implementing authentication management best practices, which
>   require periodic credential rotation.  Rotation of an entire set
>   of refresh tokens can be challenging, while rotation of a single
>   set of client credentials is significantly easier.

As  a fact, **confidential client allows you the flexibility of altering client authentication by changing the shared secret**.

Comment: Sorry, but that does not answer my question. My question basically was: Why is a shared secret (which is not possible with public clients) a good idea? Against which threat does it protect?

I am not really confusing Client Credentials with ROPC. I was merely wondering what benefit the client secret (applicable to some grants and not others) would get me?

Comment: @Wolfgang it is defined in the OAuth2.0 specification. I have added the relevant detailed and expand the answer.